# setting outgoing email smtp gmail References in header in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib, imaplib

I'm having difficulty setting the `References:` field in the header of an outgoing SMTP email for Gmail.  I'm using Python 3.8 with `smtplib` and `email.message` libraries.  The code is:

```
reference_ids = [
    '<BN8PR17MB27372595A957D7912CEE184FBF6F9@BN8PR17MB2737.namprd17.prod.outlook.com>',
    '<CAM9Ku=FZ5RGMvw3VzNrZz+DA78zyq2Am8fz9JNLmjUQ9ZEXpDQ@mail.gmail.com>',
    '<BN8PR17MB27371C71A65834531DF028BBBF6F9@BN8PR17MB2737.namprd17.prod.outlook.com>',
    '<CAM9Ku=E1wmpj=AMRhsh-Sk1RHqmK_x-J5ey8szVehefYQvn13w@mail.gmail.com>']
in_reply_to = reference_ids[0]

smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(es.smtp_server)
smtp.login(es.username, es.password)
msg = email.message.EmailMessage()
if (reference_ids is not None):
    msg.add_header('In-Reply-To', in_reply_to)
    msg.add_header('References', (' ').join(reference_ids))
msg['Subject'] = request.vars.subject
msg['From'] = es.email
msg['To'] = request.vars.to
msg['CC'] = request.vars.cc
msg['BCC'] = request.vars.bcc
msg.set_content(request.vars.message)
smtp.send_message(msg)
smtp.quit()
```

where `reference_ids` is a list of Message-IDs previous "in_reply_to"s of "message_id"s back to the originating email.

I can send the email without errors and when I view the "Show original" the References look ok.  it is the proper list of Message-IDs of the form "BNX_blah_blah@mail.gmail.com", without quotes, separated by a space.

However, when I try to later read the sent email with the `imaplib` library and `email.message_from_bytes(raw_email_response_body[1])` I get a real mess of characters.  Most of the addresses in the References loose their BNX_blah_blah@mail.gmail.com" form.  Message-ID and In-Reply-To looks ok though.

```
References: =?utf-8?q?=22=3CBN8PR17MB27372595A957D7912CEE184FBF6F9=40BN8PR17?=
 =?utf-8?q?MB2737=2Enamprd17=2Eprod=2Eoutlook=2Ecom=3E?=
 <CAM9Ku=FZ5RGMvw3VzNrZz+DA78zyq2Am8fz9JNLmjUQ9ZEXpDQ@mail.gmail.com>
 =?utf-8?q?=3CBN8PR17MB27371C71A65834531DF028BBBF6F9=40BN8PR17MB2737=2Enampr?=
 =?utf-8?q?d17=2Eprod=2Eoutlook=2Ecom=3E_=3CBN8PR17MB27377F609B669D0E72638D6?=
 =?utf-8?q?9BF6F9=40BN8PR17MB2737=2Enamprd17=2Eprod=2Eoutlook=2Ecom=3E?=
 <CAM9Ku=E1wmpj=AMRhsh-Sk1RHqmK_x-J5ey8szVehefYQvn13w@mail.gmail.com>
```

Am I encoding the References properly?  Am I decoding the References I read from IMAP properly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than hide details down here in comments, where they are harder to find and harder to read.

Comment: (That's bog-standard RFC2047 encoding, which kicks in when you try to use invalid characters in some contexts.)

Comment: so i did "msg.add_header('References', email.utils.quote(' '.join(reference_ids))) for the 6th line in the above code.  then i tried "email.utils.unquote(email.message_from_bytes(raw_email_response_body[1]))" and i'm still getting the same mess of characters.

Answer (score 1):

thanx to everyone for giving me direction, especially tripleee with "That's bog-standard RFC2047 encoding."  which led me the email.header library.

so,,, when i send the email via gmail smtp, i could set the 6th line to simply:

```
msg.add_header('References', ' '.join(reference_ids))
```

where reference_ids is a python list of straight address strings, like:

```
['<BN8PR17MB27372595A957D7912CEE184FBF6F9@BN8PR17MB2737.namprd17.prod.outlook.com>', '<CAM9Ku=FZ5RGMvw3VzNrZz+DA78zyq2Am8fz9JNLmjUQ9ZEXpDQ@mail.gmail.com>', '<BN8PR17MB27371C71A65834531DF028BBBF6F9@BN8PR17MB2737.namprd17.prod.outlook.com>', '<BN8PR17MB27377F609B669D0E72638D69BF6F9@BN8PR17MB2737.namprd17.prod.outlook.com>', '<CAM9Ku=E1wmpj=AMRhsh-Sk1RHqmK_x-J5ey8szVehefYQvn13w@mail.gmail.com>']
```

where gmail would show the list under "Show original" as a long string line with space delimited separation.

the problem comes in when you attempt to read it via imaplib where it is encoded via RFC2047.  so upon reading the email header, i processed it like:

```
import imaplib, smtplib, email
from email.header import decode_header, make_header
...
emsg = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email_response_body[1])
...
References = emsg['References']
if References:
    References = make_header(decode_header(References))
    References = str(References).strip().replace('"', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\n', ' ').replace(' '*3, ' '*2).replace(' '*2, ' ').split(' ')
```

which will faithfully return the list of Message-IDs as originally sent.  hopefully this helps a few people out there.  and, i thank everyone for the help and direction.  lucas

Comment: Uhhhh, no, that's wrong. `imaplib` (or rather `message_from_bytes`) is doing the right thing out of the box without further adornments; you are botching the `References:` on send.

Comment: ok, how should I be sending it then?

Comment: See my answer now. Going forward, please make sure you include all the required information in the question itself, not splattered around in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have uncovered a bug in Python's `email` library. The `References:` and `In-Reply-To:` headers should not be subject to RFC2047 encoding at all.

As a quick and dirty demonstration, I can avoid the problem by shortening the long ones.

As a similarly quick and dirty workaround, you can override the `email.policy` object with a different one which doesn't force these lines to be shortened. This is a slightly obscure corner of the Python `email` library; [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html) really presupposes a fair amount of prior knowledge of both email in general and Python's `email` library in particular.

```
from email.policy import default

... 

custom_policy = default.clone(max_line_length=100)

msg = email.message.EmailMessage(policy=custom_policy)

...
# in your IMAP reader
copy = message_from_bytes(imap_response[1], policy=custom_policy)
```

Notice, however, that this sets the maximum line length everywhere, not just in the headers. You'd really want to be able to override this setting just for the duration of the addition of these specific headers.

Notice also that `message_from_bytes` needs a `policy=` keyword argument to construct a modern `EmailMessage` object. Without the keyword, you end up creating a legacy `email.message.Message` object which lacks several of the modern methods of the 3.3+ `email` API.

Here's a demo: https://ideone.com/eEzIxe

Comment: I like to lay blame on Microsoft when I can, so maybe let's just say for the record that it would be extremely good if their Message-id:s were short enough to avoid this in the first place, regardless of whether this is a bug in Python.